# How to merge two polygon elements into one?

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sf

I have the shapefile below containing information on Moroccan provinces. The shapefile looks as follows:

```
> library(sf)
> library(ggplot2)
> morocco_shp <- read_sf("decoupage/Provinces_2015.shp")
> str(morocco_shp)
sf [75 × 22] (S3: sf/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ OBJECTID_1: int [1:75] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ NAME      : chr [1:75] "Assa Zag" "Guelmim" "Tan Tan" "Tata" ...
 $ pop_maroca: num [1:75] 44120 187613 1060302 117809 596891 ...
 $ pop_etrang: num [1:75] 4 195 5299 32 3708 ...
 $ pop_total_: num [1:75] 44124 187808 1065601 117841 600599 ...
 $ menages_14: num [1:75] 44124 187808 1065601 117841 600599 ...
 $ class_pop : int [1:75] 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 ...
 $ SRF       : num [1:75] 22741 11002 9498 26216 2430 ...
 $ DENSITE_14: num [1:75] 1.94 17.07 112.19 4.5 247.19 ...
 $ RuleID    : int [1:75] 1 2 5 1 5 4 5 3 5 2 ...
 $ Shape_Leng: num [1:75] 6.72 6.47 4.16 10.61 2.93 ...
 $ Shape_Area: num [1:75] 2.088 1.018 0.872 2.442 0.229 ...
 $ menage_urb: num [1:75] 3931 30332 253831 7992 124107 ...
 $ pop_urb   : num [1:75] 27333 139246 1005041 40820 508155 ...
 $ etrange_ur: num [1:75] 2 144 5259 24 3631 ...
 $ marocain_u: num [1:75] 27331 139102 999782 40796 504524 ...
 $ menage_rur: num [1:75] 1277 9882 12907 14367 19645 ...
 $ pop_rur   : num [1:75] 16791 48562 60560 77021 92444 ...
 $ etranger_r: num [1:75] 2 51 40 8 77 128 9 57 191 91 ...
 $ marocain_r: num [1:75] 16789 48511 60520 77013 92367 ...
 $ prcnt_urb : num [1:75] 61.9 74.1 94.3 34.6 84.6 ...
 $ geometry  :sfc_POLYGON of length 75; first list element: List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:348, 1:2] -8.67 -8.74 -8.76 -8.79 -8.8 ...
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "XY" "POLYGON" "sfg"
 - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
 - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:21] "OBJECTID_1" "NAME" "pop_maroca" "pop_etrang" ...
>
```

Now I want to take two provinces, `"Es Semara"` and `"Tarfaya"` (shown below):

```
> library(patchwork)
> E <- ggplot() + geom_sf(data = morocco_shp) + geom_sf(data = morocco_shp[morocco_shp$NAME=="Es Semara",], fill = "grey10") + theme_bw()
> T <- ggplot() + geom_sf(data = morocco_shp) + geom_sf(data = morocco_shp[morocco_shp$NAME=="Tarfaya",], fill = "grey10") + theme_bw()
> E + T
```

[image]

And merge them into one province, which I would call `ET`, in such a way that when I run the following command:

```
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = morocco_shp) + geom_sf(data = morocco_shp[morocco_shp$NAME=="ET",], fill = "grey10") + theme_bw()
```

It gives me the following map:

[image]

Can someone please help do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new variable that indicates which polygons should be merged and which ones not with `mutate`. Then, you can group by this new variable and use `summarise` to merge the desired polygons. Since you did not share your data, here is an example using the `nc` data from `sf`. The merged polygons are located in the center of the plot.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

# Original data
plot(nc["NAME"])
```

[image: original polygons]

```
resul <- nc |>
  mutate(group = if_else(NAME %in% c("Randolph", "Chatham"), "group", NAME)) |>
  group_by(group) |>
  summarise()

plot(resul)
```

[image: Merged polygons]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got your data, of course, and therefore can't test my approach here, but the following has worked for me before:

Buffer all states a bit (here 1 cm), so that no line will stay. Probably something like:

```
marocco_shp <- st_buffer(x = marocco_shp, dist = 0.01)
```

Then change the name of the states you want to merge:

```
marocco_shp[which(marocco_shp$NAME == "Es Semara" | marocco_shp$NAME == "Tarfaya"), "NAME"] <- "ET"
```

And then merge them:

```
st_union(x = marocco_shp[which(marocco_shp$NAME == "ET"),])
```

However, I don't know what will happen to the rest of the data of these states (like population data). It might be that you will have to remove them first.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is good, but the answer of @Jonathan is closer to what I was looking for.